# Setting GridView header text to wrap as directed

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, gridview

I have a GridView that has columns such as:

```
|    A    |    B C    |    D E / F   |
```

I want these to be wrapped in a particular way - that is, I do not want to leave it up to the browser to work out whether to wrap or not depending on the column width. So in the above example I may want the following:

```
|    A    |    B      |    D         |
|         |    C      |    E / F     |
```

I have tried using `\n` and also using `<br/>` however both of these did not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it without templates.  Just set HtmlEncode="False" on the headers with `<br />` tags in them.

Example:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="Data">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="First Line<br />Second Line" DataField="ContactID"
                HtmlEncode="False" />
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Second" DataField="FirstName" />
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Third<br />Extra" DataField="Title" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Renders:

```
First Line  |   Second  |  Third<br />Extra |
Second Line |           |                   |
---------------------------------------------
1           | Gustavo   | Mr.               |
---------------------------------------------
2           | Catherine | Ms.               |
---------------------------------------------
```

**NOTE: If you use the Designer rather than editing the aspx directly, it will change your "`<`" into "`&lt;`" when you click OK.**

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like the HtmlEncode setting affects both the HeaderText and the column data - and that seems unsafe.   There doesn't seem to be a way to turn it off for just the HeaderText

Comment: Yeah that is kind of a bummer.  Unless you are sanitizing the data in some other way, that column is vulnerable to XSS.

Answer (score 6):

If you use a template field, you can have fine grain control the header content in the header template:

```
<asp:templatefield>
    <headertemplate>
      D<br />
      E / F
    </headertemplate>
    <itemtemplate>
        <%#Eval("MyField")%>
    </itemtemplate>
</asp:templatefield>
```